# Compare multiple values against the same variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a long list of strings to compare against the same variable.

Is there a shorter way to do this?

```
if(val=="kivi" || val=="apples" || val=="lychee" || val=="banana.C" || val=="mangos")
```

Comment: Nope. That's about as short as it gets for direct string comparison.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use **[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** with array of values

```
var valArr = ["kivi","apples","lychee","banana.C","mangos"];

if(valArr.indexOf(val) > -1){
   .......
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create an array and check if the value exists in array.

[`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
var fruits = ['kivi', 'apples', 'lychee', 'banana.C', 'mangos'];

if (fruits.includes(val)) {
```

```js
var fruits = ['kivi', 'apples', 'lychee', 'banana.C', 'mangos'];

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = 'Contains? ' + fruits.includes(this.value);
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Note that this is supported in latest browsers. However, [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill) can be used in older browsers.

[**Browser Compatibility<sup>MDN</sup>**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: You love the newer methods with no legacy support don't you @Tushar :)

Comment: Do _include_ a note about [__Browser compatibility__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @RayonDabre Thanks, added :)

Answer (score 3):

Nope. That's about as short as it gets for direct string comparison.

If you have a lot of values to compare against you could put those values in an array and use `indexOf`, like this:

```
var comparisons = ["kivi", "apples", "lychee", "banana.C", "mangos" ];
if (comparisons.indexOf(val) != -1) {
    // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One line check:

```
if (['kivi', 'apples', 'lychee', 'banana.C', 'mangos'].includes(val)) {
    // Some code
}
```

Comment: When you answered a question with code snippet, please try to explain it. You can visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
myArr = ["kivi", "apples", "lychee", "banana.C", "mangos"];

if(myArr.indexOf(val) != -1)
{  
   // Element Found!!
}
```